# Variance Components in Bayesian Analysis

Tags: bayesian, anova

I've been playing around with Bayesian ANOVA versus standard ANOVA, and seem to be getting a conflict in the results that I don't think is correct. I'm curious what folk think I might be doing wrong.  Assume the following data which I've saves as some R output:

`source("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jebyrnes/a7a84ddf34cd9a421d9e5263cab41c3c/raw/93d8b14561c9c5e08086f68b0b05e71850220541/data.r")`

OK, we can fit a standard linear model here and see the F table -

```
anova(lm(PLP1.expression ~ group, data=brainGene))

##Response: PLP1.expression
##          Df  Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)   
##group      2 0.54025 0.270127  7.8231 0.001294 **
##Residuals 42 1.45023 0.034529
```

This is great.  Now, when we do a similar bayesian analysis and get the means..

```
library(brms)
library(emmeans)
brain_brm <- brm(PLP1.expression ~ group, data=brainGene)

brain_em <- emmeans(brain_brm, ~group)
```

We can see the residual sigma is about 0.19

```
Family Specific Parameters: 
      Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Eff.Sample Rhat
sigma     0.19      0.02     0.16     0.24       3454 1.00
```

OK, so, to compare this sigma to the variability due to the means, I'd like to look at the sd of those groups. We can use `tidybayes` to do this nicely.

```
library(tidybayes)
library(dplyr)
group_sd <- gather_emmeans_draws(brain_em) %>%
  group_by(.draw) %>%
  summarize(group_sd = sd(.value))
```

But, looking at the quantiles, the values are much lower than sigma

```
quantile(group_sd$group_sd)
         0%         25%         50%         75%        100% 
0.008755747 0.115908576 0.139315614 0.162789223 0.260032777
```

Compare this to the F table from the least squares fit where the F value was 7.

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here as to my calculation of the sd due to group.  What's wrong here?

As an added bonus, if I run a multilevel model

`brain_brm_h <- brm(PLP1.expression ~ 1|group, data=brainGene)`

The sd due to group is 0.3 - making me even more suspect of my earlier calculations.

Comment: Seems to me you are sampling from a population of EMMs, not a population of group means. I don't think they are the same thing, especially given only one dataset with only one set of 3 observed group means.

Comment: Given the model setup, though, these are the posterior means of each group, though.